# angularjs - sharing a service's data between 2 controllers

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, scope

I'm new to angular. I've got a small program that displays a list of names. I use a `listController` to manage displaying the list, and an `editController` for submitting more names, or resetting the list to its initial state. I hold the list of names in a service which is accessed by both controllers.

The problem is that when the `editController` resets the list, the `listController` still doesn't know about it. I've been racking by brain over this, and would appreciate if someone could have a quick look and see what the issue is?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>List of People</h1>

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in mc.list">
        {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <form ng-controller="EditorCtrl as ec">
    <h2>Add New Person</h2>
    <fieldset>
      <label>First name
        <input ng-model="ec.person.firstName" />
      </label>
      <label>Last name
        <input ng-model="ec.person.lastName" />
      </label>
      <button ng-click="ec.save()">Save</button>
      <button ng-click="ec.reset()">Reset</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Being new to javascript, using "list.length = 0" to save the reference to the array sounds deceptively trivial. But wow, it's a big deal. Lesson learned! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is how your code runs

1. MyFactory service gets initialized and creates a list data, lets called this list list1
2. MainCtrl gets initialized and takes the list1 data
3. EditorCtrl gets initialized
4. Enter some data and save the data, this gets put into list1
5. Press reset, list is recreated and list1 is not referenced in the service anymore.. now we have list2.
6. Enter some data and save the data, this gets put into list2

However, MainCtrl still has list1's data so it will not update.

The key importance is that Arrays are passed as reference not value so it's important that you dont destroy the array if you want it to behave the way it should in your app.

When you reset the list, it recreates the array and throws away its existing reference but the reference in mainCtrl is still the old reference.

```
//this will recreate the array
list = [{
  firstName: 'Rachel',
  lastName: 'Washington'
}, {
  firstName: 'Joshua',
  lastName: 'Foster'
}, {
  firstName: 'Samuel',
  lastName: 'Walker'
}, {
  firstName: 'Phyllis',
  lastName: 'Reynolds'
}];
```

So it's important you dont do that, change it to

```
var data = [{
  firstName: 'Rachel',
  lastName: 'Washington'
}, {
  firstName: 'Joshua',
  lastName: 'Foster'
}, {
  firstName: 'Samuel',
  lastName: 'Walker'
}, {
  firstName: 'Phyllis',
  lastName: 'Reynolds'
}];
list.length = 0;
angular.forEach(data, function(val){
  list.push(val);
})
```

This way you dont recreate the array, notice how there is no 'list = something'.

```
list.length = 0; //removes all items but does not remove the reference
```

After you remove the items, you can fill it up again.

Keep in mind you should also initialize the list variable as an array.

```
var list = [];
```

[Heres the example again](http://plnkr.co/edit/OWuvV03x8A1IfUBPPMRl?p=preview)